# Logging into a Django Website without Checking Users Against the Django Admin Site

Tags: javascript, python, django, active-directory

For my Project i currently check the users (username & password) against an Active Directory so once i check that the user credentials are correct but im asking to see if is possible to log the user in to the system to see (@login_required) views for example

Is this something is possible as per my requirements I am not allowed to store passwords in the Django Admin page

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is certainly possible, you just need to use a different authentication backend.

django-auth-ldap should do the job:

```
pip install django-auth-ldap
```

Now set it as the authentication backend:

```
# settings.py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
]

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.example.com"
```

There are many more configuration options to be found in the docs:

https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/